# Write 16x16 bitmap to frame buffer

Tags: performance, image, assembly, simd

The following code writes a 16x16 bitmap to a framebuffer using up to `AVX2` instuctions.  I'm sure it can be improved with `AVX512` but I'm only interested in improvements using `AVX2` and below.  Specifically, I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.  Each bit in the bitmap represents a pixel and requires a dword attribute to be written.  Each 2 byte word of the 32 byte data does one 16 pixel row for a total of 16 rows.  The below code does 8 loads and 32 stores for each 16x16 written.

```
FColor  dd  0x00ffffff  ; white
BColor  dd  0x000000ff  ; blue

ALIGN 32
bitshift_to_MSB   dd 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31

; 95 * 32 byte bitmaps (SPACE to '~')

CH_ARIAL db 0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
.
.
.
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,


    ; rdi = framebuffer address to write to
    ; edx = printable ascii character (assumed to be between 32 and 126
    sub     edx, 32
    shl     edx, 5
    mov     ecx, 8

    vpbroadcastd    ymm4, [FColor]
    vpbroadcastd    ymm3, [BColor]
    vmovdqa         ymm2,  yword [bitshift_to_MSB]
@@:
    vpbroadcastd    ymm0, dword [CH_ARIAL + edx]        ; broadcasts dword (32 bits, for 2 x 16 pixel rows)
    vpsllvd         ymm1, ymm0, ymm2                    ; shifts left according to ymm2 to set dword MSB based on 1st byte
    vblendvps       ymm1, ymm3, ymm4, ymm1              ; set dwords in ymm1 = (each dword MSB)?ymm4:ymm3
    vmovdqa         [rdi], ymm1

    vpsrld          ymm0, ymm0, 8                       ; shift 2nd byte of each dword to first position
    vpsllvd         ymm1, ymm0, ymm2
    vblendvps       ymm1, ymm3, ymm4, ymm1   
    vmovdqa         [rdi+32], ymm1

    add     rdi, 1920*4                                 ; mov down to next row of pixels

    vpsrld          ymm0, ymm0, 8                       
    vpsllvd         ymm1, ymm0, ymm2
    vblendvps       ymm1, ymm3, ymm4, ymm1   
    vmovdqa         [rdi], ymm1

    vpsrld          ymm0, ymm0, 8                       
    vpsllvd         ymm1, ymm0, ymm2
    vblendvps       ymm1, ymm3, ymm4, ymm1   
    vmovdqa         [rdi+32], ymm1

    add     edx, 4
    add     rdi, 1920*4
    dec     ecx
    jnz     @b
```